# Skype: prevent display of image when receiving link

Tags: hyperlink, skype

In Skype, when someone sends me a link (like `https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-postgresql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml`), I do not see the link as text but as an image. Clicking on the image opens the link; right click and Copy Link works, too.

I just want to see the link text, not the image. How to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found how to achiev it: in *Tools > Options > IM & SMS > IM appearance* uncheck *Show link previews*.

Comment: This setting is present only on windows at the moment. Still have no idea what to do on linux (AFAIK on mac the same problem).