# Disable hyperlink preview in Skype in Botframework

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, botframework, skype

I want to send a likn to a user through my bot to SKype channel. Is there a way to disable the Skype Link preview in the bot side?

```
session.send("Click <a href=\"https://www.google.pt/maps/place/Portugal/@35.8778914,-36.8576572,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xb32242dbf4226d5:0x2ab84b091c4ef041!8m2!3d39.399872!4d-8.224454?hl=pt-PT&shorturl=1\">here</a> to see Portugal in maps.")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use markdown?

Comment: Nope, I'll try it thanks.

Comment: I can't remember if there is this preview with markdown but it's the "official" way of formatting messages with bot Framework so you should definitely give it a try yes

Comment: @NicolasR same preview with markdown. :(

Comment: Looks like you will not be able to disable this...

Comment: Looks like the client would have to have them disabled I do not see a way to do it programmatically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809561/skype-prevent-display-of-image-when-receiving-link